# Kinetic energy of a rectangle rotating about its base

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Take a uniform rectangle with base $b$ and height $h$ and let it rotate about $b$. The kinetic energy is:

$$ T = \dfrac{1}{2} I_b \omega^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{bh^3}{3} \omega^2 $$ (with $I_b$ being the moment of inertia about the axis formed by its base)

Here is the problem:

When I try to calculate the kinetic energy via the center of mass I get a different result:

$$ T = \dfrac{1}{2}m v^2_{cm} + \dfrac{1}{2} I_{cm} \omega^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} ( \dfrac{h^2}{4} + \dfrac{bh^3}{12}) \omega^2 $$

(The CM being at a height of $\dfrac{h}{2}$)

What is the mistake here ? It seems that I'm missing an factor of $bh$ in the $v_{cm}$ term?

Comment: yes I see the difference, but the first one is purely rotational since the pivot is the base, the second one needs to have an additional $v_{cm}$ term since the pivot is about the CM.

Comment: @josephh see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/599461/does-a-rotating-rod-have-both-translational-and-rotational-kinetic-energy?rq=1

Comment: Okay. So the second equation you have used the parallel axis theorem, right?

Comment: I've taken $I_b = \dfrac{bh^3}{3}$ and $I_{cm} = \dfrac{bh^3}{12}$ as given. You could get $I_b$ from $I_{cm}$ via the parallel axis theorem .

Comment: Right. That's your answer.

Comment: @josephh wait I'm confused , could you write what you are saying explicilty ? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141292/discussion-between-lohey-and-joseph-h).

Comment: I have given you more than enough to work with. As stated before, we don't help with [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714). I'm sure as you work through this, and look at the parallel axis theorem, it will become apparent why the answer is as above. Note the missing "m" term too.

Comment: Let me point out again: Note the missing "m" term.

Comment: ok   , thank you!!

Comment: No problems and good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 1):

The moment of inertia of an uniformly dense rectangle ($ \rho(x,y) = \rho $) about its base is in fact:

$$ I_b = \rho \dfrac{bh^3}{3} = \underbrace{\rho bh}_\text{ $= \rho A = m$ } \dfrac{h^2}{3}  $$

So the $I_b$ in my original question assumes $\rho = 1$ !

(my bad here ,I blindly copied the $I_b$ online without thinking)

Also there is the error in the second $T$ (a missing $m$) which with $ m = \rho bh $ would make the two kinetic energies the same.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake is your dropping m in your second equation and you are evidently using

$m=b h$ in your first equation, so you had better use the same value of m in your second equation.